# is database access a blocking operation with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, blocking, database

I went through this [article](http://opensourceinside.blogspot.com.mt/2016/03/why-nodejs.html) and the following rose a question:

> QUEUED INPUTS If you’re receiving a high amount of concurrent data,
>   your database can become a bottleneck. As depicted above, Node.js can
>   easily handle the concurrent connections themselves. But because
>   database access is a blocking operation (in this case), we run into
>   trouble.

Isn't Db access an asynchronous operation in Nodejs? E.g. I usually perform all possible data transformations using MongoDb aggregation to minimize impact on NodeJs. Or I get things wrong?

Comment: As I know, DB access, file operation and HTTP requests, responses are counted as "async operation" in Node.JS

Answer (score -1):

that is why callbacks came into picture. that is the actual use of callbacks sine we don't know how much time db will take to process the aggregation. Db access is asynchronous just because of callbacks .

Comment: so the above snippet means that clients will have to wait for a db to respond however nodejs server will stay responsive for clients making other requests. Now it makes sense to me!

Comment: that means node.js put all the requests in a queue called as callback queue and this is the job of event loop to take the first job from this queue and execute it where there is nothing left to execute for node compiler

Comment: please check this link  http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D

Comment: thats why nodejs server is responsive because all the delay parts are in queue and will execute after all the statements has been completely executed